# Coordinates format in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, coordinates, editing

I wonder if there is possibility in ArcGIS Pro, "Edit" - "Move to" functionality to input into seconds a decimal values (DMS format).

I have tried inputting decimal value after dot and comma but it seems it is not taking into account.

Is this possible at all ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While the decimal value does not display, it is accounted for.

Using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2, I have a point at the following location:
[image]

If I use the Move To tool and add .1 to my seconds values, the point moves, but the display of coordinates in DMS do not show the decimal value.

[image]

I verified the feature moved by comparing the Decimal Degree (dd) values as well.  So while the decimal value in seconds is not displayed, it does in fact move the feature correctly.